# Draw lines in UIView not supported for multiple screen sizes?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics

I want to draw lines in a UIView with based the UIView's height. (i.e) line height should be equal to the UIView's height. For that i'm using the following code.

```
- (void)testDraw :(void(^)(UIImage *image, UIImage *selectedImage))done
    {
        CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(1000, self.bounds.size.height);
        //Begin the animation by checking the screen is retina / ordinary
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0f);
        else
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        for (NSInteger intSample=0; intSample < 1000; intSample++) {

            if(intSample % self.samplesPerSecond == 0){
                //draw separator line
                [self drawLine:context fromPoint:CGPointMake(intSample, 0) toPoint:CGPointMake(intSample, self.frame.size.height) color:self.lineColor lineWidth:2.0];
            }
        }
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        [self.progressColor set];
        UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(drawRect, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
        UIImage *tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        done(image, tintedImage);
}

//Draw the line based on the value received
- (void) drawLine:(CGContextRef) context fromPoint:(CGPoint) fromPoint toPoint:(CGPoint) toPoint color:(UIColor*) color lineWidth:(float) lineWidth{

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    //add the lines with sizes that u want
    CGContextSetAlpha(context,1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);


}
```

When i execute the above code with it working fine in 3.5 inch display, It's working fine. But when i run the same code in 4-inch the line height is not increasing based on the UIView. The lines are not working as like auto layouts.

Thanks in advance, Can anyone give your suggestion to fix this issue.